# basic html and css for a long asp.net form

Tags: asp.net, html, css

can you please help me on how to set up the html and css body parts to design a from with a long number of fields,

what would be a good measure on the css for the body and what elements do I need?

Should I stick with tables or is it better to use only div

page i am mocking :

https://lo5.medseek.com/lfserver/UH_Pre-Registration_Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are to make many fields, it could be an idea to make a method that will generate the HTML code for that field, like makeMeOneField(string name, int length, enum type) or something like that and then use that to make your fields. This will accomplish two important things: Whenever you change one things in all your fields, you only have to do it one place - in your method and secondly it makes your code way easier to look at than just having a lot of ASP and HTML spaghetti'ed together.

To your question regarding div vs. tables I would say you should chose divs. Tables were made for tabular data representation, not design. It was misused for quite some time, mostly in the 90'es and in the start of 2000, but nearly everybody is doing divs today. But that is of course up to you - it will probably look mostly the same.

Comment: Can you show me and example of doing the cells dinamically , what are the standar measures for a webpage to be compatible with most resolutions>?